# PL SQL Compund Triggers on Batch Inserts

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I've written a compound trigger to fire on inserts. Multiple inserts are batched together and sent to the DB where the compound trigger picks it up. My problem is that i need to perform an update query on the same table for certain inserts depending on the data provided by the query. I can't run a row level action since that would result in a mutating trigger table error (ORA-4091). Best thing i could think of was to have the update query in the before or after statement blocks. i cannot have it on the before statement block since each update is dependent on individual inserts and there's no way of knowing the values before actually reaching that query. so i created a "Type" table and updated it before each row is modified and then later at the after statement block i iterate through the Type table and perform update queries using the data on the table. No matter what i tried the After statement block will only perform update queries for the last insert only.

```
    TYPE apple IS RECORD ( v_size apple_t.size%Type, v_color apple_t.color%Type);
    TYPE t_apple IS TABLE OF apple INDEX BY VARCHAR2(20);

BEFORE ROW
   t_apple(key).v_size := :New.size;
   t_apple(key).v_color := :New.color;
END BEFORE ROW

AFTER STATEMENT
   Iterator := t_apple.First;
   LOOP EXIT WHEN ITERATOR IS NULL;
      UPDATE apple_t SET SIZE = 10
      WHERE color = t_apple(Iterator).color;
      Iterator := t_apple.Next(Iterator);
   END LOOP
END AFTER STATEMENT
```

This basically is how the trigger is designed. Using a second table is out of the question since trigger cost is a major factor. Any Pointers? Please and Thankyou

Comment: what value do you use as  a "key"  in the BEFOR part? is it different/ unique for earch row you are inserting ?

Comment: Is the trigger existing or you try to create. And if it exists, post the full trigger body

Comment: @schurik It's a VARCHAR value which comes from the application side. It is unique for any given insert batch but it's not unique for the whole table.

Comment: @XING trigger was not existent at the time of the question but it is now. I unfortunately cannot post the full trigger here :( but this is the basic logic structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont fully understand but I think you can get your keys after each row ,then update data in after statament block as follows.

```
declare
idx number := 1 ;
type array_t is varray(10000) of varchar2(100) ;
colorArr array_t := array_t();

    AFTER EACH ROW IS
    BEGIN
        if inserting then
           colorArr (idx) := :new.color;
           idx := idx + 1 ;
        end if;
    END
    AFTER EACH ROW;

   AFTER STATEMENT IS
    BEGIN
         for i in 1..sicilNoCol.count
         loop
            -- update here
         end loop;
    END AFTER STATEMENT;
```

or why dont you write a simple before insert trigger that you can manuplate :new.size in it? Does it give table mutable error?

Comment: Turns out that the trigger logic i was using was correct all along I simply added a extra validation to stop adding unnecessary records to the table. I'll Mark yours as the correct answer.

Comment: I also want to point out that using an array was not possible because the table handles millions of queries every minute and using a sized array would be very costly. I also needed to keep the data insert latency at minimum. This logic does not give the table mutation error since the actual update query is executed after the data insert is completed.